# Spring data r2dbc mysql can not fetch the inserted id

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I am trying to migrate my sample to the lates Spring Data R2dbc 1.0.0.RELEASE.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
    <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Schema.sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(255),
content VARCHAR(255)
);
```

My initialziation codes failed.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
class DataInitializer {

    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    public DataInitializer(DatabaseClient databaseClient) {
        this.databaseClient = databaseClient;
    }

    @EventListener(value = ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void init() {
        log.info("start data initialization  ...");
        this.databaseClient.insert()
            .into("posts")
            //.nullValue("id", Integer.class)
            .value("title", "First post title")
            .value("content", "Content of my first post")
            .map((r, m) -> r.get("id", Integer.class)).all()
            .log()
            .thenMany(
                this.databaseClient.select()
                    .from("posts")
                    .orderBy(Sort.by(desc("id")))
                    .as(Post.class)
                    .fetch()
                    .all()
                    .log()
            )
            .subscribe(null, null, () -> log.info("initialization is done..."));
    }

}
```

There is an exception when the application is started.

```sh
java.util.NoSuchElementException: column name 'id' does not exist in [LAST_INSERT_ID]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.InsertSyntheticRow.assertValidName(InsertSyntheticRow.java:151) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:0.8.0.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.InsertSyntheticRow.get(InsertSyntheticRow.java:72) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:0.8.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DataInitializer.lambda$init$0(DataInitializer.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlResult.lambda$map$2(MySqlResult.java:98) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:0.8.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1630) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:317) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.MySqlResult.lambda$null$3(MySqlResult.java:115) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:0.8.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.drainRegular(FluxWindowPredicate.java:650) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.drain(FluxWindowPredicate.java:728) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowFlux.onNext(FluxWindowPredicate.java:770) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxWindowPredicate$WindowPredicateMain.onNext(FluxWindowPredicate.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.util.DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(DiscardOnCancelSubscriber.java:65) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:0.8.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatArray.java:176) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:426) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:268) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:218) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:351) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:348) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:89) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar:0.9.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at dev.miku.r2dbc.mysql.client.MessageDuplexCodec.channelRead(MessageDuplexCodec.java:96) ~[r2dbc-mysql-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:0.8.0.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:326) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:300) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1478) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar:4.1.43.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

The complete source codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot-data-r2dbc-mysql). In the early version, I was using the [jasync based r2dbc-mysql driver](https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/tree/master/r2dbc-mysql), it worked, but after I followed the official doc to use `dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql` at this time, it failed.

**Resovled**: Use the index instread of column name, see [the comments in this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/251)

```java
.map((r, m) -> r.get(0, Integer.class))
```